# Excel: Return logic test from IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following expression:

```
=0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04
```

where $A1 is a range in my sheet from 0, 1..., 15, so it looks like this in my sheet:

```
   A        B
1  0        =0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04
2  1        =0.85*$A2*0.1/15-0.04
.
.
.
16 15       =0.85*$A16*0.1/15-0.04
```

For some values the expression is <= 0, and since '0' is not a valid case for my expression, I want excel to return N/A() instead, so that these points wont show up when plotted later.

So I want to write an expression like the following:

```
=IF(0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04<=0;NA();0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04)
```

However, I don't want the logic test expression to appear twice in the IF statement, this double the maintenance of the expression, and also I want to avoid using an extra row for the intermediate calculation, since I want the structure to be scalable to other rows with different expressions.

I would rather write it in the lines of the following:

```
=IF(expression<=0;NA();expression), where expression = 0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04
```

Any clean and easy to maintain solutions for this?

Comment: `=IF(expression<=0;NA();expression)` is exactly how you said you don't like it e.g.: `=IF(0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04<=0;NA();0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04)`

Comment: As long as I don't need an additional row to evaluate "expression", I'm happy with `

=IF(expression<=0;NA();expression)`

Comment: Use `IFERROR()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind increasing the number of operations on the formula, you could use the expression:

```
=EXP(LN(0.85*$A1*0.1/15-0.04))
```

This adjustment will return `#NUM!` everytime `$A#` is not positive and the same value as your original formula at the positive references.

**EDIT:**

I think, for some `Chart` types, you can't interrupt the plot on a desired value, **unless** if the it's cell is empty (I'm almost sure this is true for `Scatter charts`). If that's your case, you have to approach this issue with a `VBA script` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The sad truth is that Excel does work precisely the way you describe, "If A is what I want, give me A, Else B". The repetition is built into the system defined by the IF function. So, if you can avoid the use of IF you may get a better result. Here is one attempt.

`=MAX(0.85*$A4*0.1/15-0.04,1)`

This function would return 1 for any result that is smaller than 0. Now you could format the cell where the result is shown with this *Custom* format.

`[<1]"NA";0.000`

The result would be that any cell that has the value of 1 would display "NA". That **looks** exactly the way you want but it isn't because the value of the cell is still 1 and if you plot the value into a chart it will be read as 1. But you might use a helper column to translate 1s into text "N/A". Of course, the "1" can be replaced by any other value in this system. Only if you want it to be zero the cell format would be `0.0000;;"NA"`

The siolution that meets your requirement for easy handling and maintenance is a UDF. Like this one.

```
Function Plotter(Cell As Range) As Variant
    ' 057
    
    Dim Fun     As Double           ' function return value
    
    Fun = Cell.Value * 0.85 * 0.1 / 15 - 0.04
    Plotter = IIf(Fun <= 0, "NA()", Fun)
End Function
```

Call it from the worksheet with a function call like `=Plotter($A1)`
The repetition is much better hidden and it's out of sight, too. Once you get used to the expanse of space VBA provides you will find that maintenance is much easier than a crammy worksheet function. And it does return the text for values below zero.

But it would make your workbook a macro-enabled one, and for some that is a drawback.